# Customize facebook registration plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a possibility that we can change the layout or design of registration form of facebook into your desire design? I have a facebook registration form and I want to change the design of that form and turn it into the same design of my website form..

Is that possible to customize the design of facebook registration form plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I don’t think that’s possible. It is understandable, that you would want it to integrate more into the CI of your site – but on the other hand it’s important for it to be recognizable as “belonging” to Facebook, so that users are clear about what they are seeing at every time. Every site on the web having their own “version” of the plugin would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do change that much visually, since the level of customisation allowed on Social Plugins is intentionally limited so that they have a relatively consistent look and feel across the web.

You can pass in a hex value via the `border_color` property, but that's the extent of it.